# C++11 thread_local and "cannot load any more object with static TLS"

Tags: c++, multithreading, cross-platform, thread-local-storage

I ran into a not-so-good old error

```
not loaded: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so because "Cannot load library /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so: (dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS)"
```

and thought I just might avoid it by converting the pthread g/setspecific code into something using C++11 thread_local constructs (there was already an almost directly reusable implementation for the Windows Store).

No such luck. Then it struck that I might actually have been doing the opposite of what should be done (you can hardly call get/setspecific *static*). Is that the case? Or does `thread_local` just use the same pthread mechanism behind the scenes (gcc 7 on Linux)?

Out of curiosity: is there a good, lightweight and efficient cross-platform implementation for TLS that uses neither pthread (except maybe for obtaining the current thread reference) nor anything else that could lead to static TLS saturation?

Comment: gcc 7 on Linux usually does not build an executable that uses STL's thread libs without `-pthread'. thread_local is a language property but chances are good, IMO, it equally turns into pthread usage.

Comment: The *language construct* or function by which you specify an object to reside in thread-local storage has no particular relationship with how TLS support is implemented or how TLS is accessed.  With gcc, you probably want to look at the `-ftls-model` option.  In particular, you could try building your shared libs with `-ftls-model=global-dynamic`.

Comment: But that's the default for building shared libraries, no (on x86_64 at least)?